# Converting Excel to JSON SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, json, excel, parsing, sapui5

I'm using SAPUI5 and I'm trying to upload an Excel and, using the XLSX-JS library, convert it into a JSON, so I can read it and show into a table.

Here is the link to the github library project:

```
https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx
```

I'm having few troubles doing that, so I need to know what I'm doing wrong...

I'm using the WEB IDE application, and I tried to do the upload and then read the file, but doesn't work, so I decided, manually, import the excel (to try if i can read these from a path), and still not working.

Here is what I'm using to read the file I imported manually:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/m/MessageToast",
    "ExcelImport/ExcelImport/libs/xlsx.full.min"
], function (Controller, MessageToast, XLSX) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("ExcelImport.ExcelImport.controller.ExcelImportView", {
        onInit: function () {

            var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            this.getView().setModel(oModel);
            sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);

        },

        handleExcelUpload: function () {

            var url = "/files/TRY.xlsx";

            /* set up async GET request */
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open("GET", url, true);
            req.responseType = "arraybuffer";

            req.onload = function (e) {
                var data = new Uint8Array(req.response);
                var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                    type: "array"
                });

                /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
                var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];

                /* Get worksheet */
                var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
                MessageToast.show(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet));

            };

            req.send();
        }
    });
});
```

First of all, I'm having an error with the Uint8Array, which is not defined. After that, when I press the button that calls handleExcelUpload, it shows me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'read' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.req.onload (ExcelImportView.controller.js:46)
```

For now, the output I'm expecting it's just to show the JSON via a MessageToast, because, once I have the JSON, would be so easy to send into a table.

I think if I can get through this problem with an pre-imported file, I could solve the problem with the import too.

Don't know if the problem is with the Uint8Array, or with something else... help please!!

---

EDIT:

Still looking for an answer, didn't found a solution yet

---

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you haven't imported the library, but you're trying to use it. You're trying to access a property of the object XLSX which had not been defined in any way.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to paste the entire code, just the important, but it's imported on the top of my code, just like this:
```
"ExcelImport/ExcelImport/libs/xlsx.full.min"
```

Comment: We need to see your code in its entirety to be able to understand what's the problem :) It's usually good to make a working JSFiddle

Comment: Edited with the entire code! thanks in advance!

Comment: The error line is this -- yes? `var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {`

Comment: Yes, that's the line I'm having the problem with.

Comment: Then the import isn't happening. Can you log what's inside the `XLSX` object?

Comment: Hmmm, don't know if this it's what you mean, but, when I log the data variable, I get this, so it's possible that the problem it's with the import?

60,104,116,109,108,62,60,104,101,97,100,62,60,116,105,116,108,101,62,69,114,114,111,114,32,114,101,112,111,114,116,60,47,116,105,116,108,101,62,60,47,104,101,97,100,62,60,98,111,100,121,62,60,104,49,62,72,84,84,80,32,83,116,97,116,117,115,32,52,48,52,32,45,32,78,111,116,32,70,111,117,110,100,60,47,104,49,62,60,47,98,111,100,121,62,60,47,104,116,109,108,62

Comment: That's what it looks like, yes

Comment: If I change the path of the library import, I get this error: 
failed to load Javascript resource: /ExcelImport/libs/xlsx.full.min.js -  sap.ui.ModuleSystem.
Telling me that couldn't load the library, so I think that the library it's loading on my project, isn't it?

Comment: Perhaps that is some SAPUI oddity. Try to see if other libraries work and if so, what is different

Comment: I tried with the moment.js library, and it worked, the only thing I needed to do with momentjs for working, it's use this line /* global moment: true */ and it's because the name I need to use to call moment it's the same as the library (or something like that).

Comment: Sounds like the XLSX library is compiled differently. Can you verify it's not an ES6 module? Are you sure it's the right file to import? Is there a dist folder in the library folder that contains the transpiled module?

Comment: As far as I know, it's an standalone version, I used the full.min version in the dist folder of the project which is the one used in many guides.